# Calculation of xlogx with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, logarithm

I want to calculate x ln x with arbitrarily small positive x, or x = 0 without underflow or division by zero. How do I go about doing it?

I have googled "python numpy xlnx OR xlogx" with no meaningful result.

```
x = 0
a = x * np.log(x)
b = np.log(np.power(x,x))
print(a,b)

for i in range(-30,30,10):
    x = 10.**-i 
    a = x * np.log(x)
    b = np.log(np.power(x,x))
    print(a,b)

nan 0.0
6.90775527898e+31 inf
4.60517018599e+21 inf
230258509299.0 inf
0.0 0.0
-2.30258509299e-09 -2.30258512522e-09
-4.60517018599e-19 0.0
```

Edit to add: 
It was another issue causing my problem. But what is the best way to calculate xlogx? The straightforward method causes nans when x = 0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with the [xlogy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.xlogy.html) function in scipy:

```
from scipy.special import xlogy
from numpy import log

>>> xlogy(10, 10)

23.0258509299

>>> 10 * log(10)

23.0258509299

>>> xlogy(0, 0)

0.0
```

Comment: Link to [the implementation](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/special/_xlogy.pxd) for the curious.

Comment: Looking at the implementation linked by @bluenote10, it looks like for real numbers using `xlogy(x, x)` is equivalent to `0 if x == 0 else x * log(x)`.